# Using a NAT for Public Facing AWS Web Server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have read articles describing placing a public facing web server in a public subnet and placing application servers in a private subnet.  Furthermore, using a NAT Gateway to allow servers in a private subnet to communicate with the Internet, etc.

Alternatively, is it acceptable to also place your web server in the private subnet and flow all Internet traffic through the NAT Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the webserver's in the private subnet, it won't be reachable from the Internet. NAT gateways give instances outgoing access, not incoming.

However, you can have webservers in a private subnet, and serve them via an Elastic Load Balancer placed in a public subnet.

Comment: regarding your comment about NAT Gateways giving instances outgoing access, not incoming - does that apply to NAT Instances also?